# YouTube Reporting API: Create/Download reports using channel oauth token

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, reporting, youtube-analytics-api

We have a channel oauth token from a channel owner and we are able to use the YouTube Analytics API to get details, including revenue, on the channel/videos.

I would like to use the YouTube Reporting API to create a report that we need daily and not use the more resource limited Analytics API but I am not able to see the larger list (43) of report types that include system managed reports with revenue, such as `content_owner_ad_revenue_raw_a1` and `content_owner_estimated_revenue_a1` with any value for the `onBehalfOfContentOwner` argument in a `service.reportTypes().list` API call.

I can see a list of 43 available reports when using a CMS oauth token, passing the `partner_id` value as the `onBehalfOfContentOwner`.
I can not find a working value when using a channel oauth token, any value I tried (`oid` for the video for example) results in an error response.

When I use `None` as the value for `onBehalfOfContentOwner` I see a different list (for both cms and channel oauth) of 18 reports that do not include any revenue data.

What value should I use with a channel oauth to get the revenue information from Reporting API, similar data that I am able to get from Analytics API using the same token?

Snippet from the list of 43 report types that I see when using cms partner_id on a CMS level is attached.
[image: partial list from 43 report types available with a valid partner_id on cms based oauth]

The list of 18 report types that I get when I pass `None` to `onBehalfOfContentOwner` is also attached (the same list for cms and channel oauth).
[image: list of 18 report types I can see when using None on both types of oauth requests]

I tried the following:

```py
service.reportTypes().list(
            onBehalfOfContentOwner=oid,
            includeSystemManaged=True
        ).execute()
```

returns error, any other value I could think of instead of `oid` returns error

with

```py
service.reportTypes().list(
            onBehalfOfContentOwner=None,
            includeSystemManaged=True
        ).execute()
```

I get a list of 18 report types that doesn't include revenue information, also there is no `systemManaged` column.

Comment: Just an idea, but have you enabled the Reporting API from the API Library? It's different than the Analytics API.

Comment: @soniaseguz thanks for the suggestion. As I see some reports (non-financial) I assume the Reporting API is enabled for the channel, but I'd like to check and confirm. Where/how can I check/enable them using the channel oauth token?